# How to activate a miniconda environment in anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda

I installed miniconda on my macOS a few months ago.

Today I installed [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution) on the same computer.

Now I found that I can't activate a miniconda environment by running `conda activate my_miniconda_env`.

Here's my environments:

```
conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /Users/my_name/opt/anaconda3
                         /Users/my_name/opt/miniconda3/envs/my_miniconda_env
                         /Users/my_name/opt/miniconda3/envs/my_miniconda_env2
```

When I run `conda activate my_miniconda_env`, I got the following error.

```
EnvironmentNameNotFound: Could not find conda environment: my_miniconda_env
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.
```

How can I activate those miniconda environments now?

Comment: Have you seen if _Anaconda Navigator_ can give you a solution? Additionally, perhaps `conda activate /Users/my_name/opt/miniconda3/envs/my_miniconda_env` could activate your env, by passing the absolute path to it.

Comment: Using absolute path works. Thank you for your information :-)

Comment: Conda is only designed to have one install, so you shouldn’t be coinstalling Miniconda and Anaconda in the first place. One Conda install can handle all use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perhaps a bit hidden or unexpected but you can use *absolute path* to activate every conda environment. Copying from `conda activate --help`:

> ActivateHelp: usage: conda activate [-h] [--[no-]stack] [env_name_or_prefix]
>
> Activate a conda environment.
>
> Options:
>
> positional arguments:
> env_name_or_prefix    The environment name or prefix to activate. If the
> prefix is a relative path, it must start with './'
> (or '.' on Windows).

More concretely, you can write:

```
conda activate /Users/my_name/opt/miniconda3/envs/my_miniconda_env
```

and it should work.

**Note:** This post is written for the sake of completion, since Brian said in the comments that it works for him.